# Writing a project from scratch for wordpress -> use wordpress structure or custom?

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel

i will be using wordpress for an upcoming project

thing is: the main custom post_type, does it make sense to build it as wordpress post, or is it maybe more effective to create it as a complete custom table?

it is a charity software. So it will have a couple charity projects, now the question is: what is the advantage / disadvantage of using the wordpress post structure?

i give an example: using the wordpress post structure, i can use worpdress post tools to edit the fields. Disadvantage: the custom fields are stored as meta fields in a different table for no obvious reason. Advantage: i can use taxonomies and categories. Disadvantage: i cannot use the laravel scaffolding for the fields any more / i lose flexibility.

how would i decide on how I should do it?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to go with custom post type and custom fields.

**Why custom post type and custom fields?**

> It's not really matter if custom fields stores in separate table. Wordpress provides you the UI, CRUD operation function for those posts and meta. Also you could find some useful plugin if you go with the post type and custom fields ( In case if you need some quick features in future. )

**Why not custom table?**

> You have to write a tones of code
>   You have to check for the tables and code if there is any changes.
>   Takes lot of time.
>   You have to program the UI for adding posts

If you are going to use custom tables, what is the need of WordPress? You could create a Custom PHP project.

Comment: i recommend to you that you search for and start using pods http://pods.io/ i would not use relationships in pods, but the most basic things are fine, no code in DB, and they have an option to use custom tables instead of custom post types, all the UI etc gets generated for you...

Answer (score 0):

I have this debate from time to time with friends.

Both have pros and cons.

*Wordpress:*

**Pros:**

- Rapid Development (You can put together a site in literally  5 min)
- Plugins + template = No need to code
- Admin Dashboard

**Cons:**

- It's not that flexible
- You can get hack easily

---

*Project from scratch:*

**Pros**:

- Flexibility
- You can do exactly what you need

**Cons**:

- You will need to implement so many things, database design, code architecture
- It will take a long time to achieve the same in wordpress.

**Conclusion**

It really depends on the situation.

You should pick them accordingly.

But if I have to choose in your situation, you are doing a charity website, wordpress would be my choice. I will put together a simple blog in few minutes.